# Delete values of a key and keep the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to delete the values of a key, but keep the key in my dictionary.
With `dict.pop` the key is deleted and I need the key in the dict.
How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean "Delete the value"? Set it to `""`?

Comment: There is nothing like `No value`.Do you mean `None`?

Comment: Yes sorry, i have a dictionary of lists, and I want to remove all the elements of a key, but keep the key, with empty list as value.

Comment: @euler87: just set it to an empty list then.

Comment: Ok thank you all, got it now!

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the value and keep the key. *At best* you can set the value to a sentinel, such as `None`:

```
d = {'foo': 42, 'bar': 81}
d['foo'] = None
```

`None` is still a value, but in your program you can take that to mean 'no value' if that fits your use-cases.

You can then test for the sentinel:

```
if d[key] is None:
    # 'no value' case
```

If `None` is a valid value, pick a different singleton sentinel value:

```
_sentinel = object()
d['foo'] = _sentinel

if d[key] is _sentinel:
    # 'no value' case
```

If you are talking about a *list as value*, just clear the list. An empty list object is *still a value*:

```
d = {'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': ['spam', 'eggs']}
d['foo'] = []     # assign new, empty list
del d['bar'][:]   # empty list in-place
```

Comment: I am a fan of sentinels: `null = object()`, in case `None` is a valid value.

Comment: @Kay: yup, although I prefer an explicit `_sentinel` name rather than `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
dict[key].remove(value)
```